# Running a back ground service in iOS8+

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa, ios8, background-process

I have an application which needs to connect to server whenever the iPhone is active (i.e when the display screen is on). For this to work I need below 2 things.

In android we have combination of

- `BroadcastReceiver` to get notified when the screen is active
- `Services` to run the app process in the back ground to accomplish this task.

But in iOS I couldn't find any such service. Is there any way I can accomplish this task in iOS 8 ? Are there any equivalents for the above 2 in iOS ?

Comment: What do you mean "when the screen is active"? Active as in on your app, or active as in the phone is unlocked?

Comment: @pbush25 yes. When display screen is on. Or when the phone is unlocked

Comment: There is no way to make your app aware of this in iOS. Your apps have two possibilities, one where they fetch information only when they're running, or the other where you can designate them to perform specific background tasks, but this is not specific to the screen condition. In that case it would receive a notification to fetch new data and perform its fetch to be ready when the user opens the app again.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this part of the documentation on [downloading data in the background](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:). You'll want to implement `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:` in your AppDelegate, turn on "Background Modes" in the Capabilities (find by clicking top item in Project navigator, the one with the blue icon next to it), and checkmark "Background fetch".

Note that the system decides when to call `application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler:`-- it is entirely opaque to us. It is only called when your app is not the app running in the foreground.

I don't know of any way to get a notification every time the device is unlocked.